# How to split a string by space in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, string

Suppose, In title column data is stored like this

```
$title = "We are a completely vertically integrated company which ...."
```

I want to show them into view like this

```
   <h1>We are</h1>
   <h2>a completely vertically</h2>
   <h3>integrated company which ....</h3>
```

I split the title like this

```
$parts = explode(" ", $title);
```

But now, How can I join that parts for my desired output?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for here? A solution for this one specific case or a general solution? If it's a general solution you're after, you'll have to explain more about your word grouping rules.

Comment: Why don't you just put the HTML directly into your string in the desired places? e.g. `$title = "<h1>We are</h1><h2>a completely ...";`

Comment: The title is misleading: You don't seem to want to split your string by every space. So some spaces have to be different than others to make it work. What makes these spaces different? What is the rule behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array_shift() to shift the first element off from the array. Shift first 2 words from the array for h1, next 3 words for h2, and implode the rest of the array elements for h3

```
$title = 'We are a completely vertically integrated company which ....';
$parts = explode(' ', $title);

$html = '<h1>' . array_shift($parts) . ' ' . array_shift($parts) . '</h1>';
$html .= '<h2>' . array_shift($parts) . ' ' . array_shift($parts) .  ' ' . array_shift($parts) . '</h2>';
$html .= '<h3>' . implode(' ', $parts) . '</h3>';
    
echo $html;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value